# If $L$ is a left-inverse of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, is $AL$ necessarily an orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $L$ satisfies $LA = I_n$. I know that $P = AL$ is a projection, since $P^2 = (AL)AL = A(LA)L = AL = P$. I've read that the left-inverse can be used to find the least-squares solution of a linear system, which I know is given by the orthogonal projection onto $R(A)$.

Is it true that $AL$ is an orthogonal projection? Can I show that $(AL)^T = AL$?

Comment: Have you tried any specific examples to see if $P$ is orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ and $m=2$ we have $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}= I_1$$ if $ac+bd=1.$ On the other hand $$\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} a & b\end{pmatrix}  =\begin{pmatrix} ac & bc \\ ad & bd\end{pmatrix} $$ The last matrix is not symmetric if $ad\neq bc.$ For example $a=0,$ $b=c=d=1$